# What is the regex pattern for Name?

Tags: regex, validation

What is the regex pattern for these rules:

- Uppercase in the first digit of the name

**Valid: John
Invalid: JohN**

- Uppercase in the middle of the name is allowed but only once.

**Valid: McArthur
Invalid: McArThuR**

- Using apostrophe (') once only and must in the middle of the name

**Valid: Mac O'Brian
Invalid: Mac' O''Brian**

Comment: Good luck with this...

Comment: What have you tried? Per the flagging menu: _"Questions asking for code ***must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved***. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."_

Comment: The closest to solve the problem is to compare the input with a titlecased version of it. But that will likely fail on some Welsh names (and McArthur).

Comment: How about names like "Jan de Wit", "Paul-Henri Carle de Limoges", etc. How many spaces are OK. Do all "words" need to start with a capital in your world? Can more than one word have an apostrophe? How about hyphens?

Comment: [Falshoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) is an interesting read, even if you're going to decide that it doesn't apply to *your* situation.

Comment: Read the following excellent post: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - you beat me to it.

Comment: Telling somebody that their name isn't valid is generally a bad user experience.

Comment: Don't try to split up names into first and last names, either.  "Eddie Van Halen" and "Mary Ann Summers" both have three "words" in their names but they break out to "(Eddie) (Van Halen)" and "(Mary Ann) (Summers)".  What if they got married and she became "Mary Ann Van Halen"?  Or maybe she'd want to be "Mary Ann Summers-Van Halen"?

Answer (score 8):

This is a global regex that will work for all names around the world in any culture.

```
^.+$
```

You are welcome.

What you are trying to do is impose complex validation upon a very open field. Consider providing `given name` and `family name` input fields instead.

Comment: It *does* exclude the nameless... :)

Comment: I suppose you mean *given name* because in large parts (most?) of the world, the family name is the first name.

Comment: @larsmans agreed. I was aware of the problem while typing it but could not think of the correct word.

Comment: @deceze Put that down to my laziness in not looking up if i should use * or + :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're really intending this for validation (e.g. in a web form or account sign-up) I'd pay attention to Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment. It's probably better to let people spell their names however they like; there are better ways to identify trolls after the fact.

But, as an intellectual exercise, here's a regex that validates per the examples you gave.  This is PCRE syntax; you may need to adapt or amend it for your specific regex syntax or flavor:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z]?'?|'?[A-Z])[a-z]+
```

Note that you'd have to apply this to each name or name part individually, but since your validation pattern is mostly driven by Western European surname conventions, it probably makes sense to apply to the last name only.

Comment: This assumes that middle apostrophe is next to middle uppercase letter. The original question didn't have this assumption.

Comment: True; I took is as implied (apostrophe separates name-parts in Irish/Scottish style names).  But better not to make assumptions when it comes to a spec.

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Z][a-z ]*   (?:   [A-Z]?[a-z ]*\'?   |   \'?[a-z ]*[A-Z]?   )   [a-z ]+
```

Discard the whitespace outside square brackets, I've put them just to make the different parts clear.